# Syntax error near unexpected token ')' in ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Im using ubuntu server. Im trying to set the http proxy using

```
echo "export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyIP:port/" | tee -a ~/.bashrc.
```

Please note that my password contains `)(&%` special characters. When I reboot the server using `sudo reboot` I get the following error :

```
Syntax error near unexpected token ')'
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "export http_proxy='http://username:password@proxyIP:port/'" | tee -a ~/.bashrc.
```